# Zend Namespace - Check if Session Exists

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

All,

I am using Zend Framework and Zend_Session to do global session management for my application. I plan to clear all sessions on logout and hence am using the following code:

```
if($this->sessionExists())
{
    $this->destroy();
}
```

But it seems like it's not doing a good job.. I am getting an error:

```
    PHP Warning:  session_destroy() [<a href='function.session-destroy'>
function.session-destroy</a>]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session
```

How can I get rid of this error? Is there an alternative to sessionExists()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick..

```
if($this->isStarted())
{
    if($this->sessionExists())
    {
        $this->namespaceUnset("default");
        $this->forgetMe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really answers your question about the error, but is beneficial for the question:

```
$nsName = 'MyNamespace';
if (Zend_Session::namespaceIsset($nsName)) {
  echo $nsName.' exists';
}
```