# How to check if php session is valid?

Tags: php, jquery, json, zend-framework

I'm using Zend framework 1.12 to build a web app where the user has to sign in to complete tasks.

All the tasks are made through JSON calls to functions in php modules.

When the session has expired and the user wants to execute a task, the response from the JSON is 200.

There is a way to check if the session has expired?

In the controller of user validation I've:

```
   if ($User->isValid()) {
            $this->_redirect(base64_decode($this->redirect));
    } else {
        return $this->render('logging');
    }
```

Comment: May be duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586530/zend-namespace-check-if-session-exists

Comment: @ Rohit Kumar Choudhary. Hi, thanks for your answer but its not the same issue

Comment: can you explain bit more??

Comment: When you say the user has to sign in, are you using Zend Auth?

Comment: @ Tim Fountain, yes I'm using Zend Auth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, because I'm receiving the html of the logging page in the json response when the session expired, what I’ve done it's to parse this string and when it's the logging page I’ve an alert to the user like this:

```
/*....*/
switch(data.status){

        case 200:
            var loginPageTest =/<!--loggin page-->/; 
            if(loginPageTest.test(data.responseText)){
                alert("A sua sessão expirou. É necessário fazer logging");
                return;
            }else{
               /*...*/
            }
            break;
}
```